# Wireless network keeps going down on Ubuntu, especially while downloading something big

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04

Recent Linux convert and novice here. Not sure why, but my wifi network on Ubuntu 22.04 seems to go down randomly, although it seems to happen particularly when I download something big (that is, something that takes a while and hogs all the bandwidth). Like for example, while I was downloading in Firefox a version of the Eclipse IDE, my network stopped while it was halfway done. This has happened multiple times. EDIT: To be clear, it stays down when it goes down. I can't connect again until I restart, and if I try, it doesn't work and just keeps asking me for the password periodically (and the password is definitely correct).

The wifi hardware used is T-Link TL-WN722N.

I haven't found any solution to this on the net.

Not sure what I can do to give you more information. Let me know if I need to add some information and how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Release details maybe a start; if using a LTS release you have kernel stack choices (*which alter the kernel modules in use - aka drivers*).  We can't know what options you have given you've provided no details as to OS/product/release or *software stack* details.  Also if you tried any of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide would also help, including details of your wifi hardware (*device recognition & operation section shows you how to get that detail*)

Comment: I installed the latest Ubuntu release, the 22.04 LTS. The wifi hardware is T-Link TL-WN722N. Thanks for the link, I'll take a look there as well.

Comment: It's the chipset that matters to the Linux kernel, not make/model... so follow the *Device Recognition & Operation* section to get details of what is seen by the Linux kernel, or you could try `sudo lshw -C network` to list-hardware of class=network